# Spring boot and mySQL get request for one to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, many-to-many, postman

i have 3 tables in mySQL, User, Institution and Role

1. one to many relation from user to institution (one user can work at one institution, and one institution can have many users)

the institutions in my database are already inserted and the user can only work in a specific existing institution.

i manually added 2 records to my DB for user and for institution.

but when i send a getAllUsers or a getAllInstitutions request i get the following json body which is a infinite loop.

---------User model--------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="lastActive")
    private String lastActive;
    @Column(name="createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name="isBlocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    private Institution institution;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

---------institution model-----------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="institution_Id")
    private int institutionId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> user;
    
}
```

---------role model----------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="role_Id")
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

-------- the controller -----------

```
@GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return (List<User>) userrepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping("/addUser")
public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    userrepository.save(user);
    return "role saved with name: " + user.getName();
}

@GetMapping("/getAllInstitutions")
public List<Institution> getAllInstitutions() {
    return (List<Institution>) institutionrepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping("/addInstitution")
public String addInstitution(@RequestBody Institution institution) {
    institutionrepository.save(institution);
    return "institution saved with name: " + institution.getName();
}
```

--------- the api request body loop error of getAllInstitutions---------------

```
[
{
    "institutionId": 1,
    "name": "Bank Byblos",
    "type": "Bank",
    "location": "sen el fil",
    "user": [
        {
            "userId": 3,
            "name": "user1",
            "lastname": "testtest",
            "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
            "password": "user1123",
            "lastActive": "11/11/21",
            "createdDate": "06/05/20",
            "institution": {
                "institutionId": 1,
                "name": "Bank Byblos",
                "type": "Bank",
                "location": "sen el fil",
                "user": [
                    {
                        "userId": 3,
                        "name": "user1",
                        "lastname": "testtest",
                        "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                        "password": "user1123",
                        "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                        "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                        "institution": {
                            "institutionId": 1,
                            "name": "Bank Byblos",
                            "type": "Bank",
                            "location": "sen el fil",
                            "user": [
                                {
                                    "userId": 3,
                                    "name": "user1",
                                    "lastname": "testtest",
                                    "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                                    "password": "user1123",
                                    "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                                    "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                                    "institution": {
                                        "institutionId": 1,
                                        "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                        "type": "Bank",
                                        "location": "sen el fil",
                                        "user": [
                                            {
                                                "userId": 3,
                                                "name": "user1",
                                                "lastname": "testtest",
                                                "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                                                "password": "user1123",
                                                "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                                                "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                                                "institution": {
                                                    "institutionId": 1,
                                                    "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                                    "type": "Bank",
                                                    "location": "sen el fil",
                                                    "user": [
                                                        {
                                                            "userId": 3,
                                                            "name": "user1",
                                                            "lastname": "testtest",
                                                            "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                                                            "password": "user1123",
                                                            "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                                                            "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                                                            "institution": {
                                                                "institutionId": 1,
                                                                "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                                                "type": "Bank",
                                                                "location": "sen el fil",
                                                                "user": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "userId": 3,
                                                                        "name": "user1",
                                                                        "lastname": "testtest",
                                                                        "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                                                                        "password": "user1123",
                                                                        "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                                                                        "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                                                                        "institution": {
                                                                            "institutionId": 1,
                                                                            "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                                                            "type": "Bank",
                                                                            "location": "sen el fil",
                                                                            "user": [
                                                                                {
```

--------- the api request body loop error of getAllÙsers---------------

```
[
{
    "userId": 3,
    "name": "user1",
    "lastname": "testtest",
    "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
    "password": "user1123",
    "lastActive": "11/11/21",
    "createdDate": "06/05/20",
    "institution": {
        "institutionId": 1,
        "name": "Bank Byblos",
        "type": "Bank",
        "location": "sen el fil",
        "user": [
            {
                "userId": 3,
                "name": "user1",
                "lastname": "testtest",
                "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                "password": "user1123",
                "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                "institution": {
                    "institutionId": 1,
                    "name": "Bank Byblos",
                    "type": "Bank",
                    "location": "sen el fil",
                    "user": [
                        {
                            "userId": 3,
                            "name": "user1",
                            "lastname": "testtest",
                            "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                            "password": "user1123",
                            "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                            "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                            "institution": {
                                "institutionId": 1,
                                "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                "type": "Bank",
                                "location": "sen el fil",
                                "user": [
                                    {
                                        "userId": 3,
                                        "name": "user1",
                                        "lastname": "testtest",
                                        "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                                        "password": "user1123",
                                        "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                                        "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                                        "institution": {
                                            "institutionId": 1,
                                            "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                            "type": "Bank",
                                            "location": "sen el fil",
                                            "user": [
                                                {
                                                    "userId": 3,
                                                    "name": "user1",
                                                    "lastname": "testtest",
                                                    "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                                                    "password": "user1123",
                                                    "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                                                    "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                                                    "institution": {
                                                        "institutionId": 1,
                                                        "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                                        "type": "Bank",
                                                        "location": "sen el fil",
                                                        "user": [
                                                            {
                                                                "userId": 3,
                                                                "name": "user1",
                                                                "lastname": "testtest",
                                                                "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
                                                                "password": "user1123",
                                                                "lastActive": "11/11/21",
                                                                "createdDate": "06/05/20",
                                                                "institution": {
                                                                    "institutionId": 1,
                                                                    "name": "Bank Byblos",
                                                                    "type": "Bank",
                                                                    "location": "sen el fil",
                                                                    "user": [
```

i have 2 users added to my db user1 and user2 , and also 2 institutions added to my db user1 belongs to one and the user2 belongs to the other (using a foreign key institution_id in user table)
please can u help me fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your code as following:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="institution_Id")
    private int institutionId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"institution"})
    private Set<User> user;
    
}
```

Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to ignore property instution of user in your `Institution` model.
Now it won't loop, because you won't get intitutions when getting institutions data.

Try add `@JsonIgnoreProperties` in your `User` model as well, it should fix your problem.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="lastActive")
    private String lastActive;
    @Column(name="createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name="isBlocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"user"})
    private Institution institution;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

Comment: and for user ? how can i know which institution is the user working for 
i will try it now thank you..

Comment: For user leave it like it is. It should work just fine for now.

Comment: i tried it it still giving the same loop
i guess it should not be biderectional ?
i should remove the set of users from institutions ?
idk actually

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I edited it, try it like this.

Comment: okay it worked now for institution it gives me an all institutions with the users of that institution 
but now i get an error for getAllUsers

`
{
    "timestamp": "2020-08-17T10:01:21.921+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/getAllUsers"
}`

Comment: @jayzee check console in Spring. It is server error.

Comment: yes i know but it happened after adding the new code...

Comment: spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
added this it got fixed thank you

Comment: I added more code in answer to prevent not only getAllInstitution loop but also getAllUsers, also don't forget to leave a like if we helped you, bye